# Mocking EntityManager

Tags: testing, junit, mockito, entitymanager

I am getting NPE while mocking EntityManager, below is my code,

```
@Stateless
public class NodeChangeDeltaQueryBean implements NodeChangeDeltaQueryLocal {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;
    @Override
    public String findIdByNaturalKey(final String replicationDomain, final int sourceNodeIndex,
                                     final int nodeChangeNumber) {
        List<String> result =
            NodeChangeDelta.findIdByNaturalKey(this.em, replicationDomain, sourceNodeIndex,
                nodeChangeNumber).getResultList();
        return result.isEmpty() ? null : result.get(0);
    }
}
```

My Entity Class

```
@Entity
public class NodeChangeDelta implements Serializable, Cloneable, GeneratedEntity, KeyedEntity<String> {

public static TypedQuery<String> findIdByNaturalKey(final EntityManager em, final String replicationDomain, final int sourceNodeIndex, final int nodeChangeNumber) {
        return em.createNamedQuery("NodeChangeDelta.findIdByNaturalKey", String.class)
            .setParameter("replicationDomain", replicationDomain)
            .setParameter("sourceNodeIndex", sourceNodeIndex)
            .setParameter("nodeChangeNumber", nodeChangeNumber);
    }
}
```

My Test Class

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class NodeChangeDeltaQueryBeanTest {

    @InjectMocks
    NodeChangeDeltaQueryBean nodeChangeDeltaQueryBean;

    @Mock
    EntityManager em;

@Test
    public void testFindIdByNaturalKey() {
        this.addNodeChangeDelta();
        this.nodeChangeDeltaQueryBean.findIdByNaturalKey(this.REPLICATION_DOMAIN,
            this.SOURCE_NODE_INDEX, this.NODE_CHANGE_NUMDER);
    }
}
```

While debugging em is not null (also other arguments REPLICATION_DOMAIN,
                SOURCE_NODE_INDEX, NODE_CHANGE_NUMDER not null) in Entity class, whereas em.createNamedQuery("NodeChangeDelta.findIdByNaturalKey", String.class) is null.

Comment: Do you expect your mock to execute an actual query? That's not going to work. It has no knowledge of your data source, persistence context, named queries, etc.

Answer (score 1):

On the mockito wiki : [Don't mock types you don't own !](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/How-to-write-good-tests#dont-mock-type-you-dont-own)

> *This is not a hard line, but crossing this line may have repercussions! (it most likely will.)*
>
> 1. Imagine code that mocks a third party lib. After a particular upgrade of a third library, the logic might change a bit, but the test suite will execute just fine, because it's mocked. So later on, thinking everything is good to go, the build-wall is green after all, the software is deployed and... *Boom*
> 2. It may be a sign that the current design is not decoupled enough from this third party library.
> 3. Also another issue is that the third party lib might be complex and require a lot of mocks to even work properly. That leads to overly specified tests and complex fixtures, which in itself compromises the *compact and readable* goal. Or to tests which do not cover the code enough, because of the complexity to mock the external system.
>
> Instead, the most common way is to create wrappers around the external lib/system, though one should be aware of the risk of abstraction leakage, where too much low level API, concepts or exceptions, goes beyond the boundary of the wrapper. In order to verify integration with the third party library, write integration tests, and make them as compact and readable as possible as well.

Mock type that you don't have the control can be considered a (*mocking*) anti-pattern. While `EntityManager` is pretty much *standard*, one should not consider there won't be any behavior change in upcoming JDK / JSR releases (it already happened numerous time in other part of the API, just look at the JDK release notes). Plus the real implementations may have subtleties in their behavior that can hardly be mocked, tests may be green but the production tomcats are on fire (true story).

My point is that if the code needs to mock a type I don't own, the design should change *asap* so I, my colleagues or future maintainers of this code won't fall in these traps.

Also the wiki links to other blogs entries describing issues they had when they tried to mock type they didn't have control.

Instead I really advice everyone to **don't use mock** when testing integration with another system. I believe for database stuff, [Arquillian](http://arquillian.org/) is the thing to go, the project appears to be quite active.

---

*Adapted from my answer : [https://stackoverflow.com/a/28698223/48136](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28698223/48136_)*

Answer (score 0):

In Mockito, any method invocation on a mock that is not explicitly configured, always returns `null`. Therefore in `findIdByNaturalKey`, `em.createNamedQuery` is returning `null` and so NPE on `setParameter`. You need to configure it to  [RETURN_MOCKS](http://mockito.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.8.3/javadoc/org/mockito/Mockito.html#RETURNS_MOCKS).

Also, I am not sure if `@InjectMocks` supports `@PersistenceContext`. If it does not then `em` is probably null. If it does, please let me know and the above is your issue.

Comment: `@InjectMocks` is not spring / jee aware, it just tries it's best to find a matching type. It is not a real dependency injection framework.